# How to count leading characters and replace them with a &nbsp;?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of names coming back to me, and each name starts off with a couple of dashes. How do I count the number of the leading dashes?
After I get the count of the leading dashes I should be able replace the dashes with &nbsp

```js
var names = ['- Albert','-- Benson','--- Chuck','-- DeeDee','--- Ernest'];

for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
  console.log(names[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? You should have enough experience already to know you need to supply a bit more here ;) (also why would you include jquery for this purpose...)

Comment: @Icepickle, I know I should have supplied more info

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, I added the jquery tag because I am fine with whichever way its done

Comment: Assuming you mean `&nbsp;`, with a semicolon at the end, which is a valid HTML entity. Without the semicolon it's just an ampersand and some letters :).

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, if I added the semicolon in the question then it was getting ready as a line of code ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to replace leading dashes with `&nbsp;` you can simply do:

```
var names = ['- Albert','-- Benson','--- Chuck','-- DeeDee','--- Ernest'];
var fixedNames = names.map(name => {
    var parts = name.split(' ');

    // only replace dashes up until the first space
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/-/g, '&nbsp;');

    return parts.join(' ');
});
```

Comment: Wait, you don't need the count of dashes @Chris?

Comment: @Icepickle, I guess not because this does everything for me. I was going to end up doing it the long way and count the dashes then replace those all with the &nbsp

Comment: @Chris The question made it sound like these were actually unrelated, that you just wanted to know how many there are before calling replace ^_^

Comment: @Icepickle, sorry about how I explained it. Yea I just need to replace each leading dash with blank space, I figured I would have to keep a count of leading dashes to the beginning of the name itself and then wouldn't have to worry about if the name itself has any dashes because only the first ones count

Comment: @Chris not to drag this longer than it should but names like `--- Dee-dee` would still come out like `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Dee&nbsp;dee` (couldn't you add this to the question?)

Comment: I've updated my answer to show replacing only leading (up to the first space) dashes

Answer (score 2):

### Answer:

Use the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) String method with a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) that includes a global(`g`) flag.

```
    names[i].replace(/-/g, "&nbsp")
```

**Note:** If you have dashes within your names, please look at the **"Response"** section at the end of this answer, as it was brought to my attention in the comments that might be a scenario :)

---

### Why?

The String `replace` method only replaces the first instance when given a string as the first parameter. As an example:

```
"-- John".replace("-", "&nbsp");
```

Results in:

```
"&nbsp- John"
```

Since the above would only replace the first `-` character it finds, it may lead you to believe that you need to count each of them before properly replacing the string.

Since you illustrated that the real crux of the issue isn't **counting the number of dashes**, but **replacing the dashes** themselves, we can use an alternative method.

By passing as the first paramter to `replace` a `RegExp` that looks for dashes `/-/`  and combining it with a `g`(**global**) flag:

```
/-/g
```

the `replace` method will evaluate to replace as many dash characters as it can find in the first pass, not just the initial. The solution is then this:

```
names[i].replace(/-/g, "&nbsp")
```

---

### Example:

```js
var names = ['- Albert','-- Benson','--- Chuck','-- DeeDee','--- Ernest'];

for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
  console.log(names[i].replace(/-/g, "&nbsp"));
}
```

---

### Aside:

If you have no need for the original data, it would be best to create a new Array with the data instead of performing the `replace` each time you iterate:

```
 Array.from(['- Albert','-- Benson','--- Chuck','-- DeeDee','--- Ernest'], 
 name => name.replace(/-/g, "&nbsp"));
```

Or, alternatively if you need the original data:

```
   var names = ['- Albert','-- Benson','--- Chuck','-- DeeDee','--- Ernest'],
   transformed = Array.from(names, name => name.replace(/-/g, "&nbsp"));
```

---

### Response: Removing only Starting Dashes:

To be sure that you remove only the starting dashes of the string you can adjust the RegExp like so:

```
-(?![a-zA-Z])|-(?=\s|-)
```

---

### RegEx Explanation:

- The group `-(?![a-zA-Z])` says that it accepts a dash that is not followed by an alpha character.
- The `|` character is an alternation. Saying that it accepts either expressions before and after it.
- The group `-(?=\s|-)` says that it accepts a dash that is followed by a space or an alpha character.

---

### Response: Dashes in Names Example:

```js
  var names = ['- Albert','-- Benson','--- Chuck','-- DeeDee','--- Ernest-Williamson'],
   transformed = Array.from(names, name => name.replace(/-(?![a-zA-Z])|-(?=\s|-)/g, "&nbsp"));
   
console.log(transformed);
```

---

### Alternative to Using A Complicated Regular Expression:

Since RegExp can be a little daunting when you get into things like `lookAhead`, you can also use a `replacer` function, which may, at this point be easier.

A [**Replacer** function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters) is one that is passed to the **second parameter** of  a String `replace` method. It can often be utilized in place of, or in combination with, confusing Regular Expressions(RegExp).

As an Example:

```
"Blane".replace("n", function(match) { return "z" });
```

Will return:

```
"Blaze"
```

The first parameter returned to the function is the `match`, which as you can gather is the character `n` in the above example. You simply return the string that you would like to replace the match with.

You can also combine this with RegEx like so:

```
"Jiggy J. Stardust".replace(/J/g, function(match) { return "z" });
```

will return:

```
"ziggy z. Stardust"
```

---

If we provide a RegEx that gets all characters `/./g`, we can use a closure with the replacer function to determine if we've gone passed the initial dashes by setting a flag:

```
function replacer() {
  let flag = false;

  return function(match) {
    if (match === "-" && !flag) {
      return "&nbsp";
    }
    flag = true
    return match;
  }

}
```

Admittedly this may look confusing, but it's just a function that creates a flag and then returns a function. That function determines if the match is a `-` and if it is, returns "&nbsp", if it isn't it sets the `flag` so that no more dashes will be replaced.

---

### Replacer Function Example:

```js
var names = ['- Albert', '-- Benson', '--- Chuck', '-- DeeDee', '--- Ernest-Johnson'];

function replacer() {
  let flag = false;
  return function(match) {
    if (match === "-" && !flag) {
      return "&nbsp";
    }
    flag = true
    return match;
  }
}

transformed = names.map(name => name.replace(/./g, replacer()));
console.log(transformed);
```

---

### Replacer Minimal Example:

We can easily rewrite the replacer to make it more compact:

```
let replacer = ( flag = 0 ) => match => 
( match === "-" && !flag ) ? 
"&nbsp;" : ( flag = 1, match );
```

```js
var names = [ '- Albert', '-- Benson', '--- Chuck', '-- DeeDee', '--- Ernest-Johnson' ];

let replacer = ( flag = 0 ) => match => ( match === "-" && !flag ) ? "&nbsp;" : ( flag = 1, match );

transformed = names.map( name => name.replace( /./g, replacer() ) );

console.log( transformed );
```

---

### Hope This Helps!

This is quite a bit more than I expected to write, and I don't expect to get a checkmark because some others are brief and to the point, but I do hope that this answer at least gives a little enlightenment into some of the nifty areas of `replace`.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: I just noticed this, this would replace all dashes, and I only need to remove the leading dashes. So if -- John-son, then it would come back as &nbsp;&nbsp;John&nbsp;son

Comment: @Chris updated the answer. Hopefully this helps! I'll also add an alternative with a replacer function in just a moment.

Comment: Wow, that is one awesome explanation. Good job on adding all that

Comment: @Chris it's no problem. I particularly love the pattern of using the  `replacer` function with an all characters RegEx(`/./`) as it allows for a quick iteration over a string in one pass, and can often times negate type coercion to an Array.

Answer (score 0):

I see people are fans of the regular expression. All well and good until someone gets poked in the eye (remember kids, don't run and use regex at the same time!). For giggles, I present to you a simple method for replacing the initial dashes with "$nbsp;". Comments in the code for the curious.

```js
var names = ['- Albert','-- Benson','--- Chuck','-- Dee-Dee','--- Ernest'];

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
  // Makes an array from the name using the spread syntax
  const chars = [...names[i]];
  // Goes through the dashes. If the first character is not a dash, exits immediately
  // if it encounters anything other than a dash, exits immediately
  for (let c = 0; chars[c] === '-' && c < chars.length; c++) {
    chars[c] = '&nbsp;';
  }
   
  // Make the array a string again
  names[i] = chars.join('');
}

console.log(names);
```